# Authorization in single page applications

Tags: security, authentication, authorization

I'm looking at security methods for a SPA using webapi as a backend.  I'm confused on security methods.  From what I am understanding, authentication verifies the user identity.  So submitting a username and password and receiving back a token.  Then authorization allows the user to access certain methods with that token.  Not sure if I have that right.

My question is say for example this particular user is allowed to access method `GetAccountData` with parameter `AccountNumber=1`. This user should be able to see account number `1` only, NOT account number `2`.

How do I prevent the user from using a program like Fiddler to send that same request, using their token they received, but changing the parameter to `AccountNumber=2`?

The bottom line is I want to prevent the user from accessing an different account that they should not see.

Please let me know if I am not explaining this properly.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication is about stating who you are and proving it like: I am user "..." and this is my password "...".

Authorization is about defining access rights at the functional level (which functionality the user may call) and data level (which data the user may have access to).

Access control is about enforcement of authorization rules. Sometimes the terms authorization and access control are used interchangeably.

Now back to your question. You can't prevent the user from messing with the request. You should never trust the incoming data and always validate the input. If the user should not have access to the data he requested, you must check it and reject the request (with http status 401 if the user is not authenticated or with http status 403 if the user is not authorized).

Comment: appreciate the input.  so since you can't prevent the user from messing with the request how do people handle this?  Once I receive the request, how do you go about checking it ?

Comment: You can do it manually like you know the user and you know the `accountNumber` he wants to have access to. You need to check in code, if you should allow this. You need to have in your data or database some model of what the user may or may not do and perform checks against that model.

Comment: so for one request from user... like "getMyData", I should actually perform 2 executions.  1.  checking if that user has access to that account.  then 2.  actually getting the data?

Comment: Yes, you should perform more than one action.

Comment: so maybe this is paranoia... but what if they change the username as well... so to an employee they know who might have access to more data.

Comment: Well, you authenticate the user. If you do it properly, then you know who he is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218445/discussion-between-solarissf-and-marek-puchalski).